# Delete all li's that doesn't have a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` list. In that, there is some `li`s. I want to remove ALL `li`s that *don't* have children with the class `noremove`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2.1</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
            <li>Item 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3
        <ul>
           <li class="noremove">Item 3.1</li> 
           <li>Item 3.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="noremove">Item 4
        <ul>
            <li>Item 4.1</li>
            <li>Item 4.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 5
        <ul>
            <li>Item 5.1
                <ul>
                    <li class="noremove">Item 5.1.1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

After the script is run, I want it to look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 3
        <ul>
           <li class="noremove">Item 3.1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="noremove">Item 4</li>
     <li>Item 5
        <ul>
            <li>Item 5.1
                <ul>
                    <li class="noremove">Item 5.1.1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, Item 3 is not removed, as it have a child node with `class="noremove"`. However, Item 3.2 is removed, as it doesn't have `class="noremove"` nor any children with the class.

How can I make a script that does that? It needs to run recursively on the list, and I can't think of how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want to find all li that doesnt have the noremove class, and see if they have a child with the class noremove:

```
$("ul li:not(.noremove)").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find(".noremove").length === 0;
}).remove();
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kNvyF/

Comment: Is it possible to tweak the code, so it doesn't remove the children of .noremove? So Item 4.1 and Item 4.2 is not removed (I know they are in my example, but have changed my mind).

Comment: haven´t really tested it but something like: http://jsfiddle.net/kNvyF/3/ should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').not('.noremove').remove()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It doesn't check recursively, so only li there would be left is Item 4, as it is the only parent node with 'noremove'.

If you had tested it and compared it to the output I want, you could have seen this.

Comment: That'll remove all of the list items save for three that have the class and the OP wants to maintain the parents of the list items with that class.